# Converting Formulas to Ultimate Cell References [IndexMatch, Offset, Indirect]

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was wondering if it would possible to convert Formulas to the most final cell reference using VBA Macro.

For eg.
Let's say the formula in Cell H2 is as follows

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,MATCH($F2,$C$2:$C$7,0)),"")
```

Now let's say the evaluation of this index match function directs us to Cell D3 (ie the Value in Cell F2 was same as that in Cell C3).
So would it be possible to convert this formula to

```
=D3
```

As its final evaluation was the value of D3.

To get to this I've tried using

```
Evaluate(ActiveCell.Formula).Address
```

The above line of code will work on just plain functions such as simply INDEX MATCH, OFFSET, INDIRECT. But once you add IFERROR it fails to function.

Would it be possible to create a universal macro which would break down all of the formulas within a cell to their most ultimate cell references

Thanks.

Comment: INDEX resolves to a usable cell reference; e.g. `D3`. You get the value from it because that you are essentially saying `=D3` as your evaluate shows. Other functions (VLOOKUP for one) actually resolve straight to the value so you cannot get the resulting cell; e.g. `=<value in D3>`. IFERROR removes the cell reference so it can determine if an error was thrown. I don't see how you would ever get a one-size-fits-all VBA evaluation procedure.